# ¿Cuál es el origen de "pifia"?

Tags: etimología, coloquialismos

Una *pifia* es, en habla coloquial, una acción hecha con por error:

> El gol en propia puerta de Roberto Carlos fue la **pifia** del año. ¡Qué mala pata!

Veo que el DLE lo define

> [**pifia**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=SxvzhuK)
>   `De pifiar.`
>
> 1. f. Golpe en falso que se da con el taco en la bola de billar o de trucos.
> 2. f. coloq. Error, descuido, paso o dicho desacertado.
> 3. f. Bol., Chile y Ec. [escarnio](https://dle.rae.es/?id=GCGada7).
> 4. f. Bol. y Perú. [rechifla](https://dle.rae.es/?id=VQIKhrF).

Y, a su vez:

> [**pifiar**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Sxy688i)
>   `Del a. al. medio pfîfen 'silbar'.`
>
> 1. tr. Bol., Chile, Ec. y Perú. Reprobar mediante silbidos.
> 2. tr. Bol. y Perú. [escarnecer](https://dle.rae.es/?id=GCBp1Gp).
> 3. tr. Méx. [robar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=WXknmzC) (‖ tomar para sí o hurtar).
> 4. intr. Hacer que se oiga demasiado el soplo de quien toca la flauta travesera, defecto muy notable.
> 5. intr. Hacer una pifia en el billar o en los trucos.
> 6. intr. coloq. Cometer cualquier error, descuido o desacierto. U. t. c. tr.
> 7. prnl. coloq. Bol. y Chile. Equivocarse torpemente.

Es decir, que *pifia* vendría de *pifiar*, que a su vez viene de la voz del alto alemán * pfîfen*.

Sin embargo, en catalán también existe la palabra [*pífia*](http://www.diccionari.cat/lexicx.jsp?GECART=0103920) y se explica su etimología como:

> alteració popular de *pifre*, instrument de so molt agut, fàcil de ser desafinat i de produir una nota falsa

Es decir:

> alteración popular de *pifre*, instrumento de sonido muy agudo, fácil de ser desafinado y de producir una nota falsa.

Y efectivamente [*pifre*](http://www.diccionari.cat/lexicx.jsp?GECART=0103925) en catalán existe y es una variedad del flautín, cuyo nombre viene del alemán *Pfeifer*, del latín vulgar para vg. *pipa 'flautita'.

¿Existe relación entre esta etimología y la que se usa para el castellano? ¿Realmente decimos *pifia* como derivación de simplemente *silbar*?

Comment: La raíz protogermánica de *pfîfen* y de *Pfeifer* es la misma y proviene del latín, como ya viste. Evidentemente ha habido un entremezclamiento considerable con idas y vueltas entre germánico y romance ahí.

Answer (score 3):

Según Corominas, el instrumento que en catalán denominas *pifre* se denomina en español *[pífano](https://dle.rae.es/?id=SxtV1IT)*:

> Flautín de tono muy agudo, usado en las bandas militares.

En su libro sobre etimologías dice:

> **PÍFANO**, h. 1600, antes *pífaro*, 1517. Del alem. ant. *pfifer* íd., deriv. de *pfifen 'silbar' (hoy *pfeifen*); por conducto del it. *pìffero*.

Y a continuación añade lo relevante para esta pregunta:

> De *pfifen* quizá procede *pifiar* 'hacer que se oiga demasiado el soplo del que toca la flauta', 1817; 'dar un golpe en falso', teniendo en cuenta el jergal *pifar* 'picar el caballo para que camine', 1609.

Las voces *pifia* y *pifiar* aparecen por primera vez en el DLE en 1803, con su significado relativo al golpe en falso que se da con el taco en la bola en el *juego de villar*. Sí, con *v*. Añade que el taco "al resbalarse forma un sonido semejante á esta voz". Entiendo que se refiere al sonido "pif".

En el suplemento de ese mismo año se recoge también:

> Hacer que se oiga demasiado el soplo del que toca la flauta travesera, que es un defecto muy notable.

Las dos acepciones hacen mención a errores, y de hecho la segunda incluye mención a los instrumentos de viento. De hecho, si el *pífano* es un instrumento de sonido agudo, *pifiar* podría significar "hacer que una flauta suene como un pífano".

En todo caso, el significado de la palabra ya se había extendido a otros campos en su uso figurado:

> *Las frutas están en su punto; y al hacer el matiz colorado, por donde hoy se pudiera comenzar en el lugar que corresponde en su respectivo papel de frutas, como se hizo la grande, no fíe vuesamerced su hermoso color a Matiz, porque sabe vuesamerced que lo pifiará.*
>
> José Celestino Mutis, "A don Salvador Rizo, Mayordomo de la Expedición [Cartas de José Celestino Mutis]", 1789 (Colombia).

Entiendo pues que la acepción de "golpe en falso" pudo venir influencia por *pifar*, y la de "tocar mal la flauta" sí que pudo venir del alemán "soplar" o tal vez de "pífano". Ahora bien, ¿cuál de las dos acepciones, la del billar o la de la flauta, generó la acepción de "error, descuido", introducido en el DLE en 1852? Pudo ser cualquiera, o incluso las dos combinadas dado que ambas refieren errores. Pero ambas apuntan, según Corominas, al aleman *pfifen*.

Como curiosidad, la acción de *silbar* se popularizó en América, donde en algún países (Ecuador, Bolivia y Chile según el DAMER) [significa](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=pifiar) "reprobar a alguien mediante silbidos".

Answer (score 0):

La palabra pifiar viene efectivamente del alemán *pfeifen* (silbar) y hacer referencia a los silbidos de descontento del público ante algo que no le gusta (un ejemplo claro podría ser el que apuntas, cuando un jugador realiza una mala jugada o falla algo que se daba por gol).

En España, al menos, pifiar no es sinónimo de silbar y nunca se utiliza en ese contexto, únicamente se utiliza para una acción errónea o poco afortunada.

Comment: De ahí me pregunta: ¿es realmente el origen el que detalla el DLE o va más por el lado de la etimología dada en el catalán, indicando sonidos extraños, "pifiosos"?

Comment: Ahora comprendo tu pregunta. Indagando algo, he encontrado https://ca.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pifre que el propio instrumento que comentas debe su nombre a la palabra alemana pfeiffen, que es la flauta. Por lo tanto entiendo que, aunque provenga del catalán, realmente provendría del alemán, puesto que es el verdadero origen.